# wrap a ul around a group of li's jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, html-lists

Hi I cant seem to get a ul wrapped aournd a group of li. the wat i have it the closing  tag does not get added to the end of the loop it puts it on one line link this 
 `<ul class="links"></ul>`

```
    //parse the AllLinks.xml file
function xmlParser(xml) {
    $(xml).find("header").each(function(){
        var headerlabel = $(this).attr("Label")
        $("#allLinksContainer").append("<h5 class='heading'>" +headerlabel+ "</h5><ul class='links'>");

                //get label content
                $(this).find("link").each(function(){
                    var label = $(this).find('label').text()
                    var url = $(this).find("url").text()
                    var id = $(this).find("id").text()
                    $("#allLinksContainer").append("<li><a id='" +id+ "' href='" +url+ "'>" +label+ "</a></li>");
                });//end links
        $("#allLinksContainer").append("</ul>");    
    });//end header
}// close xmlParser function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function xmlParser(xml) {
    $(xml).find("header").each(function () {
        var headerlabel = $(this).attr("Label") $("#allLinksContainer").append("<h5 class='heading'>" + headerlabel + "</h5>");
                var ul = $("<ul class='links'></ul>");
        $(this).find("link").each(function () {
            var label = $(this).find('label').text();
                        var url = $(this).find("url").text();
                        var id = $(this).find("id").text();
                        ul.append("<li><a id='" + id + "' href='" + url + "'>" + label + "</a></li>");
        });
                $("#allLinksContainer").append(ul);
    });
}
```

Comment: that was it thanks maybe you could explain to me how that is working it looks a little confusing

Comment: We are creating a UL before looping the link elements and then appending the LI as it created. At the end of the loop we are adding the UL element to the "#allLinksContainer"....

Comment: i get the var ul and adding the ul.append we are adding before the li loop is that correct? but i dont get the last call $("#allLinksContainer").append(ul); this i just dont seem to understand

Comment: You need to append the UL that you created before the loop. Else it wont be displayed in "#allLinksContainer"

Answer (score 0):

Or you could add all the LI items then select them with a new jQuery and use `$("#allLinksContainer li").wrap("<ul></ul>")`

[More info here](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)